# Kendoui treeview expand clears checked nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, treeview

First the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/M5W65NLUcBXDmlNVu6dt?p=preview

In the above plunkr I have created 2 simple treeviews:

1. Uses angular-kendo
2. Uses jquery

I'm trying to open the nodes using the "expand" method.

The problem is, that when I expand a node, it clears the checkboxes.

Anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is some sort of interaction between defining a template and setting `checkChildren` to `true`.

- If you remove the template it displays correctly the checkbox and works fine.
- If you set `checkChildren` to `false` it works fine (despite it does not have the *three state* behavior for the parent node).

Try removing the template so your code should be something like:

```
$scope.treeView.options = {
    dataSource: $scope.treeView.nodes,
    checkboxes: {
        checkChildren: true
    }
};
```

There is also some problem when `checkChildren` is `true` and a parent node is `checked`: it is rendered as checked or not checked but it is not possible to have it in the third state (some children checked and some not).